# Get list of all URL names in Django to make Active links in Navigation

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am putting together a template tag for active/currently visited links in a navigation bar so I can easily add the proper active CSS class to the link.

I have created code that works fine for either a mix of passed in urls with the same url-parameters included, but it does not allow me to pass in urls that have different params.

`{% make_active 'index' %}`

and

`{% make_active 'users' 1 %}`

could not be grouped together accurately as

`{% make_active 'index~users' 1 %}`

because I am using `reverse()` to see if the url exists.

What I want is to just check the names from each of the url pattern files in my project and if the name exists, then I return the appropriate active class...but I cannot figure out how to simply grab the names. Is this possible, or can someone help with the code?

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def make_active(context, view_names, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    if not kwargs.pop('class', None):
        class_to_return = 'sidebar-item-active'
    else:
        class_to_return = kwargs.pop('class')

    request = context.get('request')

    if not request:
        raise Exception('A request must be passed in for this to work')

    names = view_names.split('~')
    print(names)
    current_url_active = False
    for view in names:
        print(view)
        try:
            # always include the client url
            args_to_use = [request.client_url]
            # append the passed args into the args for reversing the url name
            args_to_use.extend(args)
            reversed_path = reverse(view, args=args_to_use)
            print(reversed_path)
            current_url_active = True
        except NoReverseMatch:
            current_url_active = False
            continue

        if current_url_active:
            break

    return class_to_return if current_url_active else None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to gather the url names using dynamic imports, but after figuring out what I wanted to do I learned that I did not even need to go through the complexity of gathering all url names as there was an easier solution.

Anyways here is the code for the initial issue:

```
def get_url_names():
    from django.apps import apps

    list_of_url_names = list()
    list_of_all_urls = list()
    for name, app in apps.app_configs.items():
        mod_to_import = f'apps.{name}.urls'
        try:
            urls = getattr(importlib.import_module(mod_to_import), "urlpatterns")
            list_of_all_urls.extend(urls)
        except ImportError as ex:
            # is an app without urls
            pass
    for url in list_of_all_urls:
        list_of_url_names.append(url.name)

    return list_of_url_names
```

**Real Solution**

While making my initial issue work, I figured out all I needed to check was if I was on the current url name, which is easy to gather with `request.path_info`. So now my code could be changed like so:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def make_active(context, view_names, *args, **kwargs):

    if not kwargs.get('class', None):
        class_to_return = 'sidebar-item-active'
    else:
        class_to_return = kwargs.get('class')

    request = context.get('request')

    if not request:
        raise Exception('A request must be passed in for this to work')

    names = view_names.split('|')
    current_url_name = resolve(request.path_info).url_name
    for view in names:
        if view == current_url_name:
            return class_to_return
```

And now I can return the correct active link CSS class with my url tag like so:

```
 <div class="collapse {% make_active 'users_index|users_actions|groups_index|groups_edit|users_create' class='show' %} " id="userCollapse">

    <div class="card card-body">
        {% if perms.users.view_customuser and perms.users.view_staff %}
            <a class="dropdown-item {% make_active 'users_create|users_index|users_actions' %}"
               href="{% url 'users_index' CLIENT.url_base %}"><i
                    class="fas fa-users"></i>
                <span class="nav-item-text">&nbsp;Users</span>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if perms.auth %}
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class=" dropdown-item {% make_active 'groups_index|groups_edit' %}"
               href=" {% url 'groups_index' CLIENT.url_base %}">
                <i class="far fa-user-plus"></i>
                <span class="nav-item-text">&nbsp;Group Permissions</span>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```